# Jquery .val() change not taking effect until page Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am newer to Jquery so I may be overlooking something incredibly simple here.

I am trying to change the value within a input when a page loads so the default DUE_DATE on a ticket is updated.  My problem here is I am playing with manually changing the value but when I load the page there is no change to my due_date field.  HOWEVER if I REFRESH the page, the value change takes place.  I've looked around at intense AJAX reloads and such but that just seems like it can get messy QUICK.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){
var NEWDD='';
    NEWDD=$j('div h2 span:contains("Report Request Queue"):last').text();
    if(NEWDD == "Report Request Queue") {
        $j('span[id="editable_due_date"] input[name="fields[due_date]"]').val('03/24/2014');
        //$j('span#noneditable_due_date').append('03/25/2014');
        //alert("Kurtis to add Formula for 2 weeks to due-date on ExtendDueDate.js");
        }
else    {
    return true;
}

});
```

I've tried changing the .ready(function() around to different things but no real effect.  I'm just curious as to why this would take effect when RELOADING or REFRESHING a page but not when I bring the page up for the first time.

(if the Jquery looks odd to you, it's because this isn't straight jquery in HTML yet a plugin for the KACE device in which I am making JS to be called upon.  Unfortunately I am not able to modify the PHP or HTML but have to work THROUGH Jquery JS to make any kind of changes to my webapp.)

Comment: You have to run this on an interval or after an event, otherwise it will only ever run once, on page reload.

Comment: Wouldn't the initial page load be the event?

Okay then I ask the simple question:  What is the EASIEST, CLEANEST, event that I can make happen on this page when it loads?  An auto-refresh when it loads?

Comment: When i say page reload, i mean full page reload, not an ajax update. To run the code after an ajax update, use the ajax success callback.

Comment: Right, full page reload.  Alright I will do some more research into the AJAX callbacks in the meantime.  I was just hoping to avoid having to add some ajax callback set of lines before any number of .js.

Comment: There are global ajax events, but they can only be used if you are performing ajax requests with jQuery. `ajaxStop`, `ajaxComplete`